# Wakanda ssjs logging library needed

Tags: logging, wakanda, ssjs

Is there a recommended logging library for Wakanda ssjs that provides configurable levels with development/production switches?

Answer (score 1):

Try this [one](https://github.com/Wakanda/logger) it handles log levels, log format, flush delay